# Does Paypal has an OpenApi specs? need something like swagger.json or yaml

Tags: c#, paypal, swagger, openapi

Don't won't write api calls by myself. The best way - generate it by some tool. So i looking for some OpenAPI specs for PayPal Rest API

Already tried export this specs from theirs Postman collection, but it is not valid specs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2023 Update: https://github.com/paypal/paypal-rest-api-specifications/tree/main/openapi

---

At the time of this writing (Dec 2022) there are no specs.

The Postman collection has samples which may be useful, but they are simply examples (not complete specs)

Comment: Sad, anyway thx for the answer

Comment: PayPal now has OpenAPI specs here: https://github.com/paypal/paypal-rest-api-specifications/tree/main/openapi